# Is it possible to `tail -f` the output of `dmesg`?

Tags: bash, command-line, tail

I want to do something like

```
dmesg | tail -f
```

but it doesn't work:

I use Mac OS X v10.6.7 (Snow Leopard). By doing that, `tail` will exit, instead of monitoring the output.

I wonder if there is a way to do it, or an equivalent command.

P.S., I don't think a `while` loop will be a good enough idea.

Comment: that works fine on my Ubuntu 10.04LTS box. A workaround would be to tail whatever logfile that syslog is putting kernel messages into.

Comment: On Mac OSX, that file is /var/log/kernel.log

Comment: @Marc Sorry I added my machine spec now. @bobDevil That is cool, but seems that the output is different from dmesg. However this one looks nicer

Comment: @Anonymous 2: Unfortunately, `kernel.log` does not contain the same output as `dmesg`. For example, for a damaged drive, file read errors in `dmesg` specify exactly which file could not be read, while `kernel.log` unfortunately provides only the less-than-helpful notice: `disk0s2: I/O error.`

Comment: Since linux 3.5, you can do dmesg -w.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/95842/how-can-i-see-dmesg-output-as-it-changes

Comment: You can do `sudo dmesg >> "$TMPDIR/dmesg.log"; tail -f "$TMPDIR/dmesg.log"` on Mac.

Comment: Perhaps change the accepted answer to [Maxim's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/289239/is-it-possible-to-tail-f-the-output-of-dmesg/734756#734756)? It is 2020 and most users would like to find that answer first, I think.

Answer (score 195, accepted):

You are probably looking for some combination of messages from various log files. Try:

```
tail -f /var/log/{messages,kernel,dmesg,syslog}
```

…to get a pretty good overview of the system. If you want more or less than that, research what log file the messages you want to see are being placed in.

Also look into using `multitail` to file and color code and filter multiple log files at once.

**Edit:** This wasn't very relevant when I answered this, but as this page gets a lot of hits I'm thought it worth mentioning since kernel 3.5, you can do this:

```
dmesg -w
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up re: `multitail`. Looks interesting. In the case of OS X it'll be something like: `tail -f /var/log/{system.log,kernel.log}`.

Comment: `system.log` and `kernel.log` do not contain the exact output of `dmesg` on OS X. For example, for a damaged drive, file read errors in `dmesg` specify exactly which file could not be read, while `kernel.log` unfortunately provides only the less-than-helpful notice: `disk0s2: I/O error.`

Comment: For the record, this answer doesn't work on OS X Mavericks (10.9) or Arch Linux.

Comment: @Dan On Arch you probably don't have a syslog daemon installed or its service enabled. I've noticed that isn't part of the base package set even though it's pretty fundamental. OSX is BSD based and has different paths for a lot of things. You'll need to figure out how and where your system handles logging and adjust. My answer is pretty generic and covers most FHS based distros with syslog enabled, but there are also lots of variant implementations.

Comment: I'm running ubuntu 14.04 and the following tells me whether the link is up or down:  `sudo tail -f /var/log/kern.log`

Comment: ++ on the edit.

Comment: Just to point out that `dmesg -w` is not dependent on systemd.

Answer (score 93):

On Linux, since kernel kernel 3.5.0 you can use:

```
dmesg -w
```

Also on systems with `systemd` you can use:

```
journalctl -kf
```

Comment: `dmesg -w` is the absolutely nicest solution. Unfortunately, even Ubuntu 14.04 doesn't seem to be ready for this because the user space tool doesn't support it yet.

Comment: This answer definately deserves more upvotes now.

Comment: yes, this is a nice little nugget. can be made human readable with: dmesg -wH

Comment: This works on [Ubuntu 19.10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_19.10_(Eoan_Ermine)) (Eoan Ermine).

Comment: `dmesg -Hw` common useful options for human readable + tail.

Comment: the author of the question specifies macos, why provide answers for GNU+Linux?

Answer (score 60):

## Just make it @#$%ing work

1. You want to print output of dmesg, constantly, immediately
2. Dmesg is printing the kernel ring buffer (see `man dmesg`)
3. The kernel ring buffer is a special proc file, `/proc/kmsg` (see `man proc`)
4. Read `/proc/kmsg` directly, ie `cat /proc/kmsg`.

Now, if you read the friendly proc manual, it'll sternly warn you to let only one user (who must be privileged) read `/proc/kmsg` at a time. Whatever syslog implementation you have should be doing this, and presumably it works with `dmesg`. I dunno, I'm out of my league here, just paraphrasing the manual. So while this is the "just make it @#$%ing work" way, consider the next couple methods first.

## Man page approved: watch + dmesg

On one linux box I use with systemd init*, dmesg.log isn't written to very often, perhaps not at all? The best way I found to read the kernel log buffer continuously is with `watch`. Something like this should get you started (adjust for how many lines fit in your terminal):

```
watch 'dmesg | tail -50'
```

## watch + dmesg + daemon + tail -f

A more convoluted solution might use watch to write dmesg output to file, which you could then `tail -f`. You'd probably want this running as a daemon. A proper daemon would also gzip and rotate logs. The following bash code is untested, unworking, and only intended to convey an idea. @Brooks Moses's answer has a [working version](https://superuser.com/a/451650/66724).

```
watch 'dmesg >> /var/log/dmesg.log | tail -1'
```

* tangent, cause this is a question about an apple desktop os: when systemd is around, don't bother with `dmesg`; use `journalctl -xf` (maybe w/ `-n 100` to also show the previous 100 lines)

Comment: OS X does not have `/proc`, however the rest of your answer is applicable. `watch` can be installed from MacPorts: http://www.macports.org/

Comment: @Ivan Vučica Ah, good to know. Wonder where OSX represents the kernel ring buffer..

Comment: Looks like it's directly in the kernel memory. Source code for Apple's `dmesg` implementation: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/system_cmds/system_cmds-230.7/dmesg.tproj/dmesg.c Quick Googling doesn't mention anything about it being represented in the filesystem :/

Answer (score 22):

Here's a variant on [djeikyb's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/289239/is-it-possible-to-tail-f-the-output-of-dmesg/295929#295929) that's actually tested, and fixes a couple of bugs.

```
watch 'sudo dmesg -c >> /tmp/dmesg.log; tail -n 40 /tmp/dmesg.log'
```

The important trick is that we're doing `dmesg -c`, which clears the ring buffer after it prints -- thus, each time through we're only printing what's new since the last time.

You'll need to be root to do that, thus the `sudo`.  There's also a bugfix; instead of trying to both dump the output to a file and pipe it to tail (which doesn't work), we're just reading from the newly-written file.

We could do just `dmesg > /tmp/dmesg.log` and overwrite the whole file each iteration, but that's a lot of I/O and also risks losing the file if the computer crashes in the middle of an overwrite.

You could also do something similar that's more closely like `tail -f` with a `while` loop that executes `dmesg -c` and `sleep 1` forever (see Ben Harris's answer).  However, since this is actually clearing the kernel message buffer as it's running, you may also want to pipe things into a logfile in case you want them later.

Answer (score 8):

This may work for you

```
while true;do sudo dmesg -c;done
```

Keep in mind that the '-c' flag clears the message buffer into stdout. The 'sudo' is unnecessary if you are root. If you feel this is eating too much of your CPU resource, try adding a 'sleep 1' before the loop is done.

Comment: Feel free to cite your sources: http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/applications/36555-tail-dmesg.html#post730211

Comment: Quick and dirty. Dirty because it only works if you are the only one user doing this. Otherwise each user gets only half of the messages

Answer (score 5):

I did this before seeing this post:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# "tail -f" for dmesg
# Keeps last printed line. Anything sorting "gt" will be newer

$|=1;

my $y = '';

while(1) {
    for my $k (`dmesg`) {
        if ($k gt $y) {
            print $k;
            $y = $k;
        }
    }
    sleep 1;
}
exit;
```

Answer (score 4):

### Here are some ideas for limited environments

Environments such as embedded or pre-boot, where watch, tail, cat, dd and other commands might not be available, might need different gymnastics.

This is what some lightweight Linux distributions do:

```
while dmesg -c >> /tmp/dmesg.log; do sleep 0.1; done & tail -f /tmp/dmesg.log
```

It backgrounds the while loop (with &) while tailing the generated output.

If you can't write to /tmp:

```
mount -t tmpfs - /tmp 

# or 
mount -t ramfs - /tmp 

# or use /dev/shm instead of /tmp - which is available in newer environments
```

If you don't have tail, you can

```
cat /tmp/dmesg.log

# or 
dd if=/tmp/dmesg.log 

# or
dd if=/tmp/dmesg.log 2>/dev/null
```

Or you might be in a busybox environment that doesn't have dmesg linked, then just:

```
busybox dmesg -c
```

You might also need to

```
busybox sleep
```

instead of sleep

If you don't have sleep:

```
while dmesg -c; do echo >/dev/null; done
```

If you don't have "dmesg":

```
while sleep 0.1; do cat -v /proc/kmsg; done
```

This only works if nothing else is reading from here. You might also have a /dev/kmsg.

### Bonus tip:

If you don't know what you have, and you don't have "ls", just:

```
busybox ls

# or simply:

echo *
```

Comment: Please can you explain why this is a solution.

Comment: It's what some distributions do behind the scenes. It polls the kernel ringbuffer and logs it to /tmp/dmesg.log every 0.1 seconds in a background job while it tails that output. Also, it's the only method that will work if you don't have something special running in the background - or if you've killed all background processes and services and you're doing emergency troubleshooting.

Comment: Seems simpler to use `watch`

Comment: If you have it available :-) sometimes you're in an environment where you don't even have tail... then you can use cat /tmp/dmesg.log, or dd even... If you can't write to /tmp, and can't mount -t tmpfs - /tmp, or ramfs, or write to /dev/shm/... then you can just while dmesg -c; sleep 0.1; do echo >/dev/null; done, if you don't have sleep, just while dmesg -c; do echo >/dev/null; done; Sometimes you don't even have ls... then you just do echo * :-D

Comment: In the answer, not in comments. Can the answer be updated?

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to do:

```
tail -f /var/log/messages
```

Comment: On most systems, the dmesg log file is just a static dump of the dmesg buffer after system boot completes. After that, any new kernel messages usually go into another log file and the dmesg file will stay unchanged until reboot.

Comment: I don't know about "most" systems, but none of the GNU Linux systems I admin behave that way. `dmesg` reports a current set of the latest messages from the kernel, usually specific to the hardware subsystems.

Answer (score 3):

I use this alias in /root/.bashrc;

```
alias dwatch='watch -n 0.1 "dmesg | tail -n $((LINES-6))"'
```

which follows dmesg and adjusts the lines for whatever terminal it's called in.

*edit*: As lots of people have pointed out, it's as easy as `dmesg -w` since kernel 3.5.0.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
dmesg | tail -f /dev/stdin
```

Comment: This merely tails the *current* dmesg 'state', then hangs out without returning to the command prompt.  It will not have the desired effect, because dmesg (without the -w parameter) exits once it completes outputting the current 'state'.

Answer (score 0):

Under the current Ubuntu (I am using [Ubuntu 12.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_12.04_LTS_.28Precise_Pangolin.29) (Precise Pangolin)),

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
6< <( cat /var/log/syslog |grep -F  'kernel: '; sudo cat /proc/kmsg) cat /dev/fd/6
```

( the sudo command need sudo privilege )

Please also try another one like:
6< <( dmesg; sudo cat /proc/kmsg) cat /dev/fd/6

Answer (score 0):

I used this code to look for a special kernel event and piped it a "callback" process:

```
while true ; do dmesg -c ; sleep .1 ; done \
| grep --line-buffered  -o $pattern \
| ...
```

Answer (score 0):

On macOS, you can use the command `log` to watch logs on the command line. Use `log -?` or just `log` for help. It is a very good command line alternative to the GUI app `/Applications/Utilities/Console.app`. To continuously watch all system logs there is a stream mode:

```
log stream
```

The output is colourized and easy to read. Eventually, you may get too much information! In that case, I think that `multitail` recommended earlier in this thread by @Caleb is a very good option. Just select the files to watch:

```
multitail /var/log/system.log /var/log/*/launchd.log
```

PS: tested in macOS Monterey

Answer (score -3):

This might be useful:

> dmesg | tail -f -

pipes the output of `dmesg` through tail using the `-` operator as a shortcut to standard output.

Comment: This is the code from the question which does not work.

Comment: It doesn't work because `dmesg` closes output after closing once. `tail -f` can't change this anymore.

Comment: This does not work - it just displays the last 10 lines and stops. Tried on [Ubuntu 19.10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_19.10_(Eoan_Ermine)) (Eoan Ermine).