# dmesg.log on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, boot, logging, dmesg

Mac OS X does not seem to dump the exact output of `dmesg` to a file. I need to log the dump of `dmesg` to the disk.

`kernel.log` and `system.log` do not contain the required information. Only output of `dmesg` tells me which file failed to read from a faulty drive.

Compare output in `kernel.log`:

```
Oct 25 19:28:31 The-Evil-Lion kernel[0]: disk0s2: I/O error.
```

with the output of `dmesg`:

```
         0 [Level 3] [ReadUID 0] [Facility com.apple.system.fs] [ErrType IO] 
[ErrNo 5] [IOType Read] [PBlkNum 338383504] [LBlkNum 0] [FSLogMsgID 626287415] 
[FSLogMsgOrder First] 
         0 [Level 3] [ReadUID 0] [Facility com.apple.system.fs] 
[DevNode /dev/disk0s2] [MountPt /Volumes/Macintosh HD] 
[Path /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/user/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.scheduler.5D78E5A0-512D-52FF-8FC8-CBCEC048CC69.plist] 
[FSLogMsgID 626287415] [FSLogMsgOrder Last]
```

(newlines added for readability)

Actual issue is that I cannot type `dmesg` during the boot, for obvious reasons. Dumping the `dmesg` to a file during boot would be extremely helpful.

Comment: This link is related: http://superuser.com/questions/289239/is-it-possible-to-tail-f-the-output-of-dmesg

Comment: @MathewEley Not really: look at my comments over there and re-read my question. Console output is not the same as the contents of those files.